# SSIS job dynamic output filename using SSMS 2008 without Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have searched and have not found an answer for my following question:

I am running an SSIS package created from the Export data task for a database, in SSMS jobs. I want to add month and year to the file name when it is created but don't have access to Visual Studio. How would I do this in the Job Step Properties? Or would I need to do it on the SSIS package creation?

I could create a .bat file that could update the file name after the completion of the job but I would rather have it all done in one go.

Thanks.

SQL 2008 R2

--NO Visual Studio--

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using the Export Data Wizard.  You would need to edit the SSIS package to do this.

Technically you could do this without Visual Studio, since an SSIS package is just a text file, but you would really have to know what you are doing.  I wouldn't want to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You're allowed to run Powershell scripts as job steps. Roughly the same as your .BAT file idea, but you could at least have it run in-line, manage it within the Job Agent, etc.